# WPF : how to customize ComboBox's dropdown list selecting item style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I want to customize ComboBox's dropdown items' selection style, like the blue selection rect below:

[image]

but I can't find what kind of style is controlling this item. so far i doubt maybe ContentTemplateSelector property of ContentPresenter do the trick but I don't know how to customize ContentTemplateSelector's style.

so anyone please tell me how to customize the selection item style in dropdown panel?

edit: I want to know the mouse-hover style on dropdown item.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling WPF ComboBox items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746306/styling-wpf-combobox-items) (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8746619/1506454)

Comment: sorry @ASh, the duplicate is talking about listing items' style, but I want to know how to customize listing items' mouse-hover style.

Comment: that means you need a different trigger (for `IsMouseOver` property)

Comment: @ASh no it's not work. IsMouseOver will effect on item itself, but mouse-hover style for listing item still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the `ComboBox` in design mode in Visual Studio or in Blend and choose Edit Additional Templates->Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle)->Edit a Copy.

This will copy the default template of the `ComboBoxItem` containers into your XAML markup and you can then edit it as per your requirements.

Look for the resources with the x:Keys `ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewHover.Background`, `ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewSelectedHover` and `ComboBoxItem.ItemsviewHoverFocus.Background` and change the colour of these.

There is no property of the `ComboBox` that you can simply set to change the selection colour on Windows 8 and later. Please refer to the following blog post for more information: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/04/30/changing-the-background-colour-of-a-combobox-in-wpf-on-windows-8/.