# 2 Different ComboBox Styles with 2 Different ComboBoxItem Styles

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have 2 ComboBox-Styles in my WPF-Application. They're look both like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyComboBox1}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                ...
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyComboBox1}">
             ...
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers />
</Style>
```

Now I want to style the ComboBoxItems for each ComboBox in a different way. How can i do this?

Comment: You are showing combobox style. Give them `x:Key` and specify combobox style as static resource. As to your question *" I want to style the ComboBoxItems"* - you can use datatemplates, or combobox style with set `ItemTemplate` (not `Template`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling WPF ComboBox items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746306/styling-wpf-combobox-items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ItemContainerStyle` property

```
<Style TargetType="Combobox" x:Key="myStyleOne">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">

                <!-- put your style here -->

            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And then you can use your style like the following.

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource myStyleOne}" />
```